# My ubuntu 18.04 won’t load after recent update

Tags: boot, 18.04, macbook-pro

I'm trying to fix my hard drive.
It's an encrypted hard drive.
I'm using a live CD.
And I'm using a MacBook Pro.

Reinstall the GRUB of sda1 into the MBR of sda
chroot: cannot change root directory to 'grub-install': No such file or directory
grub-install /dev/sda: exit code of grub-install /dev/sda:125

---- Grub-install verbose

### chroot: cannot change root directory to 'sh': No such file or directory

/usr/sbin/grub-install /dev/sda: exit code of grub-install /dev/sda:125
---- End of grub-install verbose

chroot  update-grub
chroot: cannot change root directory to 'update-grub': No such file or directory
umount: /proc: target is busy.
umount: /dev/pts: target is busy.
umount: /dev: target is busy.
mount: /mnt/boot-sav/sda3: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'.
mount /dev/sda3 : Error code 32
mount -r /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
mount: /mnt/boot-sav/sda3: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'.
mount -r /dev/sda3 : Error code 32

An error occurred during the repair.

You can now reboot your computer.​

Comment: Welcome to AU. To allow us to properly help you, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1184077/edit) your question with more information: Are you executing as an administrator? Which update caused these problems? What have you tried so far? Also, large blocks of raw output from terminal are not always helpful. Consider formatting or shortening the output to only include errors that are relevant to the issue, or make a link to [Pastebin](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1184077/edit) with the raw output

Comment: Update sudo apt and install but then laptop died/shut off after. Using a live cd to try to repair by boot repair. My macbook won’t read my internal hard drive now after it crashed. Connected the hard drive by sata reader. Hard drive still intact.